# Pytube.AttributeError: 'StreamQuery' object has no attribute 'download'

Tags: python, pytube

```py
from pytube import YouTube
ssilka = input('Введи ссылку: ')
yt = YouTube(ssilka)
yt.streams.filter(only_video = True, res='1080p').download(filename=namevideo)
```

При скачивание ошибка

```
  yt.streams.filter(only_video = True, res='1080p').download(filename=namevideo)
AttributeError: 'StreamQuery' object has no attribute 'download'
```

Answer (score 0):

вместо

```
yt.streams.filter(only_video = True, res='1080p').download(filename=namevideo)
```

нужно добавить

```
yt.streams.filter(only_video = True, res='1080p').first().download(filename=yt.title)
```

UPD.
из твоего примера, я смог установить видео при помощи кода:

```
from pytube import YouTube
ssilka = 'youtube.com/watch?v=QUnOBmIBIAM'
yt = YouTube(ssilka)
stream = yt.streams.filter(only_video = True, res='1080p').get_by_itag(299).download()
```

Comment: yt.streams.filter(only_video = True, res='1080p').first().download(filename=yt.title)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'
все равно ошибка

Comment: можешь прописать stream = yt.streams.filter(only_video = True, res='1080p') print(stream), и хотелось б узнать, что выйдет

Comment: [<Stream: itag="299" mime_type="video/mp4" res="1080p" fps="60fps" vcodec="avc1.64002a" progressive="False" type="video">, <Stream: itag="303" mime_type="video/webm" res="1080p" fps="60fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">]

Comment: ошибка с nonetype означает то, что видео с качеством 1080 не существует в списке. Значит у нас неверна одно значение. Значит можно сделать куда легче, чтоб скачать видео. При помощи get_by_tag(). Этот код должен работать **yt.streams.get_by_itag(299).download()**.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'
Такая же ошибка

Comment: Хотелось б узнать, какое видео ты хочешь скачать, если не секрет? Попробую его через код скачать с качеством 1080

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUnOBmIBIAM как для примера

Comment: щас обновлю пост

Comment: 1920x1012, в таком качестве качает